# tQuery event handler on cube

Tags: webgl, tquery

I just started trying webgl with tQuery and well..
the simpliest code is:

```
var world = tQuery.createWorld().boilerplate().start();
var object = tQuery.createCube().addTo(world);
```

now I want to emit some data to node if there's been clicked on that cube,
but it doesnt really work, I tried different versions like:

```
$('canvas').click(function(e){
    socket.emit('foo', { msg: 'cube clicked'});
});
```

up to

```
$(tQuery('cube')).on('click', function(e){
    socket.emit('foo', { msg: 'cube hovered'});
});
```

but it's not only triggered if I click on the cube, it's also triggered if I click beside the cube -> it's triggered if I click anywhere on the tQuery surface

how to solve that?

greets

Answer (score 1):

```
tQuery('cube').on('click', function(e){});
```

this should do it